# why os module has no way to delete non-empty directory?

Tags: python, shell, operating-system

Python has 3 main functions for deleting stuff

os.remove / os.unlink

```
In [2]: os.remove?
Signature: os.remove(path, *, dir_fd=None)
Docstring:
Remove a file (same as unlink()).
```

os.rmdir

```
In [3]: os.rmdir?
Signature: os.rmdir(path, *, dir_fd=None)
Docstring:
Remove a directory.
```

but this can't delete non-empty dir, as can be seen:

```
In [4]: os.rmdir('bla')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1907b7b0ecd9> in <module>
----> 1 os.rmdir('bla')

OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: 'bla'
```

The solution is the 3rd function: `shutil.rmtree`

My question is, why don't we have a common function for all of those operations? (A simple wrapper for Shell's `rm` with it's `"r" / "f"` options)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `os` module is not a wrapper for shell commands. `os.rmdir` is a wrapper for the C [`rmdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rmdir) call, which is a low-level operation that cannot remove entire directory trees. Similarly, `os.unlink` is a wrapper for the C `unlink` function. (`os.remove` is also a wrapper for C `unlink`, rather than C `remove`, confusingly.)

If you want higher-level operations, some of those are available in `shutil`. For example, [`shutil.rmtree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree) can remove an entire directory tree. This is not the default behavior for `os.rmdir` because that would be error-prone and more expensive.

Comment: So you are saying `os` module restricts itself to low level operations rather than os-usefull operations (such as deleting an entire did tree)? I don't see the merit in that in a language like python...

Comment: @CIsForCookies: Low-level operations are useful, as are low-power operations. I hope you don't issue an `rm -rf` for *all* your deletion operations in the shell.

Comment: No doubt. However I did expect a versatile toolbox from `os` even if it's not low level. And I usually rm -rf dirs, and rm files, as I should, but even if would have rm -rf only files, I don't see that as a big deal. rm -rf. Gets things done ;)